# Use contexts with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I want to use contexts with jasmine so I can organize what my mocks return. Here is some pseudo code to demonstrate what I want to do. I expect both of these expectations to pass:

```
describe('a module', function(){
    var whatTheFunctionReturns;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('anApp', function($provide){
            $provide.value('aFactory', { aFunction: whatTheFunctionReturns })
        }
    });

    describe('when the function returns alpha', function(){
        whatTheFunctionReturns = 'alpha'

        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect(aFactory.aFunction).toEqual( 'alpha' )
        }); 
    });
    describe('when the function returns beta', function(){
        whatTheFunctionReturns = 'beta'

        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect(aFactory.aFunction).toEqual( 'beta' )
        }); 
    });
});
```

Please read the above carefully. Do you see what I'm trying to do? The code

```
$provide.value('aFactory', { aFunction: whatTheFunctionReturns })
```

is written once in a beforeEach block, but the variable

```
whatTheFunctionReturns
```

is changed in the two describe blocks, `when the function returns alpha` and `when the function returns beta`.

However, it doesn't work. Here is some real code where I'm trying to test a controller and mock out a factory that it depends on:

```
describe('firstController', function(){
    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller
    var message = 'I am message default'

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('App',function($provide){
            $provide.value('ServiceData', { message: message})
        });
        inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$controller_){
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_
            $scope = $rootScope.$new()
            $controller = _$controller_
            $controller('firstController', { '$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope' : $scope })
        });
    });

    describe('when message 1', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            message = 'I am message one'
        });
        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect($scope.serviceData.message).toEqual( '1' ) // using wrong data so I can see what data is being returned in the error message
        }); 
    });

    describe('when message 2', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            message = 'I am message two'
        });
        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect($scope.serviceData.message).toEqual( '2' ) // using wrong data so I can see what data is being returned in the error message
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the error message I get back:

```
Firefox 34.0.0 (Ubuntu) firstController when message 1 should get data from a service FAILED
    Expected 'I am message default' to equal '1'.

Firefox 34.0.0 (Ubuntu) firstController when message 2 should get data from a service FAILED
    Expected 'I am message one' to equal '2'.
```

It's half working. The variable is being updated, but only in the last describe block (`'when message 2'`). **Here's what I expected to be returned:**

```
Firefox 34.0.0 (Ubuntu) firstController when message 1 should get data from a service FAILED
    Expected 'I am message one' to equal '1'.

Firefox 34.0.0 (Ubuntu) firstController when message 2 should get data from a service FAILED
    Expected 'I am message two' to equal '2'.
```

How can I achieve this? Do you see what I'm trying to do with the describe blocks?

Comment: Why dont you do `beforeEach(function(ServiceData){
            ServiceData.message = 'I am message two'
        });`

Comment: @Chandermani You'd need `inject()` as well

Comment: You should take a look at sinon for mocking/stubbing

Comment: Thats correct @james, i forgot that part.

Comment: @james I've taken a small look at sinon...would that allow me to use contexts?

Answer (score 8):

You misunderstood how Jasmine builds the test case before executing each test.

Take a look at this and execute it:

```
describe("Test", function(){
    console.info("Calling beforeEach() before describe()");
    beforeEach(function(){
        console.info("Running before()");
    });

    console.info("Calling describe() A");
    describe("describe A", function(){
        console.info("Calling it() A 0");

        it('should A 0', function(){
            console.info("Running it() A 1");
            expect("test to be").toBe("implemented");
        });

        console.info("Calling it() A 1");
        it('should A 1', function(){
            console.info("Running it() A 2");
            expect("test to be").toBe("implemented");
        });

        console.info("Calling it() A 2");
        it('should A 2', function(){
            console.info("Running it() A 3");
            expect("test to be").toBe("implemented");
        });
    });

});
```

In the console you will observe this:

```
Calling beforeEach() before describe()
Calling describe() A
Calling it() A 0
Calling it() A 1
Calling it() A 2
Running before()
Running it() A 1
Running before()
Running it() A 2
Running before()
Running it() A 3
```

Whats going on here?

When you call `describe()` the code within the callback functions you provide will be executed. Subsequent calls to other `describe()`s will execute their callbacks to. Each invocation to `it()`, `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` will queue the passed callback in an internal queue tree, the *before* will be prepended to each branch, the *after* will be appended to that branch. Then the queue is being shifed one by one and Jasmine will execute the stored callback for each step.

When looking to your first code this means all your assignments of `whatTheFunctionReturns` are executed, then each `it()` (preceeded by `beforeEach()`) is being executed

---

What you should do:

```
describe('a module', function(){
    var whatTheFunctionReturns;

    // pepare to run in beforeEach()
    function _beforeModule(){
        module('anApp', function($provide){
            $provide.value('aFactory', { aFunction: whatTheFunctionReturns })
        }
    }

    describe('when the function returns alpha', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
           whatTheFunctionReturns = 'alpha';
           _beforeModule();
        });

        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect(aFactory.aFunction).toEqual( 'alpha' )
        }); 
    });
    describe('when the function returns beta', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
           whatTheFunctionReturns = 'beta';
           _beforeModule();
        });

        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect(aFactory.aFunction).toEqual( 'beta' )
        }); 
    });
});
```

You have to wrap assignments into `beforeEach()` or `it()` blocks.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg, I'm not sure what impact of [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27668957/revisions) has to the meaning of my suggestion. I'd prefer to revert it to the previous revision without wrapped `inject()` calls around the `it()` callbacks since the original code posted by the TO doesn't contain them too. And in my opinion the error primarily lies in the misunderstanding how Jasmine will execute the test.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. While the code in your last block does work (all expectations passing), it stops working when I try to inject my controller: 

    `inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
        scope = $rootScope.$new()
        $controller('firstController',
         { $scope : $scope }
 );
    });` When I use `inject`, the same behaviour I described before occurs. whatTheFunctionReturns is set to undefined, and then alpha, and not beta...

Comment: Andrew's modification reverted. Of course, my adaption was not complete: the code that is being executed in the first `beforeEach()` has to be called after the assignment in the other `beforeEach()` calls. Last code fixed. Note: the first/topmost `beforeEach()` block does no longer exit, the code that has been executed in that `beforeEach()`  is now called in "`_beforeModule()`"

Comment: Thanks a lot...clientside testing is a nightmare compared to serverside! Anyway, what do you think of the following. This is my full spec:

http://pastebin.com/Lm73NqeZ

Am I doing it right?

Comment: @try-catch-finally, I had tried out your code and the only way I could get it working was to add the inject.  I don't mind the reversion since my changes were not exactly relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Jasmine has no concept of [Contexts](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-context) in its [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), meaning that it is technically impossible to reuse your expectations body with dynamic scope and test its behaviour against different values. Everything you do in order to get this level of reusability with Jasmine will be a workaround, not designed by the creators.

In your demo code, when you call $controller function inside the first beforeEach it will resolve all its dependencies using the default value no matter what you do.

```
$controller('firstController', { '$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope' : $scope })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you encounter is that the variable used to assigne your 'message' in your service is just a value object. It's a javascript problem more than a jasmine problem.

It does not matters that you modify it *after* you assign it to the object that you provide to the service. For example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
a = 2;
console.log(b); // will print out '1'
```

What you want is to be able to modify the object that you provided to your service *after* your first beforeEach, just like so:

```
describe('firstController', function() {
    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, serviceData 

    beforeEach(function(){
        serviceData = { message: 'I am message default' }
        module('App',function($provide){
            $provide.value('ServiceData', serviceData) // keep a reference to the object
        });
        inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$controller_){
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_
            $scope = $rootScope.$new()
            $controller = _$controller_
            $controller('firstController', { '$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope' : $scope })
        });
    });

    describe('when message 1', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            serviceData.message = 'I am message one' // that way, you modify the object that your 'ServiceData' provider holds.
        });
        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect($scope.serviceData.message).toEqual( '1' )
        }); 
    });

    describe('when message 2', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            serviceData.message = 'I am message two'
        });
        it('should get data from a service', function(){
            expect($scope.serviceData.message).toEqual( '2' ) 
        });
    });
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure about the inner workings of *$provide.value* . If the above don't work, it might be because the object given to $provide.value function is cloned internally.